# Executar uma função de classe baseada em uma propriedade

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, typescript, angular

Por favor, preciso executar uma função de uma classe dentre várias classes que só sei qual é a correta à partir do valor de uma de suas propriedades.

Eu crio as classes por exemplo:

```
 public tabelaSerie = new clsTabela('Serie');
 public tabelaAlunos = new clsTabela('Alunos');
 public tabelaNotas = new clsTabela('Notas');
```

Assim eu instancio uma classe setando a propriedade "tableName" com o nome da tabela em uso nesta classe.

A classe tem a função "locate(key)". Agora eu preciso usar a função "locate" em uma classe que tenha a propriedade "tableName" igual a "Alunos".

E não existe como eu fazer desta forma (exemplo hipotético):

```
clsTabela('Alunos').locate(chave);
```

Ou seja, usar a funçao locate na classe que tenha a propriedade tableName igual a "Alunos" mas que eu não sei qual destas classes instanciadas é.

Eu teria que percorrer as classes uma a uma verificando qual delas tem esta propriedade setada com este valor "Alunos" e então executar a função locate desta classe. Algo como percorrer verificando com um typeOf (mas não seria com typeOf)

E também precisarei saber como eu encontro uma lista de objetos para dentre eles identificar quais são desta classes instanciada.

Exemplo Hipotético:

```
matricula = 543768776;
objetos = >>Objetosqueexistem<< // Não sei de onde obter esta relação de objetos
foreach (var obj in objetos) {
    if ( obj.hasOwnProperty('tableName') ) {
        if ( obj.valueOfProperty('tableName') == 'Alunos' ) {
           obj.locate(matricula);
        }      
    }
```

Logicamente na prática não é fácil saber qual a classe, no meu uso esta classe pode variar, pode não ser exatamente "Alunos", precisarei fazer esta execução dentro da classe base, eu seja, depois que ela for instanciada ela terá que executar o locate em outra classe que depende de qual ela mesma seja. Muita gente sempre pergunta qual o uso para poder raciocinar melhor na resposta então por isto explico que é imprevisível mesmo saber qual classe vou executar a função, terei mesmo que localiza-la para então aplicar a função com parâmetros pois esta execução se dará apenas dentro da classe, não é uma execução no meu código no nível das minhas regras de negócio.

Obrigado pela atenção, abraço!

Comment: Sinceramente essa é uma solução errada, se usasse o que a linguagem já tem ficaria muito mais simples. Use um *array* associativo e boa. Essas classes são só enfeites que não trazem utilidade.

Comment: Maniero, pela hora de sua resposta vejo que não leu minha edição onde acrescentei do "Exemplo Hipotético:" até o final. Discordo do seu ponto de vista. Eu criei classes que me permitem hoje criar um ERP em meia hora, e como agora, estou procurando mais conhecimento para aprimorar ainda mais suas funcionalidades. Às vezes pensamos que a pessoa está indo por um caminho errado e além de responder exatamente o que ela pergunta tentamos orientar para uma solução melhor e agradeço quando sai melhor do que esperamos pois muda o rumo de tudo para melhor. Mas a princípio desejo mesmo esta resposta.obg.

Comment: Ah, ok, agora entendi, é que eu trabalhei em uma empresa que centenas de engenheiros qualificados levaram décadas para criar um ERP, por isso não sou a pessoa adequada para responder isso. Boa sorte, você vai precisar.

Comment: Tranquilo amigo, mesmo assim gostaria que continuasse acompanhando pois são as mínimas coisas que resolvem os maiores problemas, com o desenvolver da questão pode ser você a saber o detalhe que vai me ajudar. Obrigado, abraço!

Comment: @MarceloVareladaSilva, você tentou criar um array, chave/valor para armazenar as instâncias das tuas classes? A partir da chave você conseguiria obter a instância, independente do tipo e executar o método locate. Por exemplo `teste: { [tableName: string]: {} } = {};`, você adicionaria `teste['Serie'] = new clsTabela('Serie');` e obteria com `let obj = teste['Serie']; obj.locate(chave);`

Comment: @KelvynRisso , Sim, havia testado assim e consigo acessar os valores mas quando os modifico eles não são modificados na origem, como um twowaydatabinding, e na verdade o meu grande objetivo não é só obter um valor mas também setar um valor. tentei tambem obter com um @ input mas não deu certo. Estou pesquisando typescript para saber como passar este parâmetro mas na condição twowaydatabinding. Assim quando eu mudar de registro na tabela Master a tabela MasterDetail observando aquele valor recarregar seus dados. Mas o caminho é por ai mesmo, obrigado pela atenção! abraço!

Comment: @KelvynRisso ... explicando melhor... desta forma passando como parâmetro array quando eu mudo de registro na tabela Master a Master que foi passada como parâmetro continua estática, ela não acompanha as mudanças da Master origem. A única forma que consegui foi passando a Master como DI (injeção de dependência). Ou observando por fora da classe.

Comment: @KelvynRisso ... se fosse um componente visual eu passaria um [(tabelaMaster)]="tblMaster" e la dentro com o @ Input(tblMaster)  eu manipularia a tabela Master de Origem mas não estou acertando e achando material na net que explique como eu passo um parâmetro para uma classe na condição twowaydatabinding.

Comment: @MarceloVareladaSilva, Não sei se entendi direito, mas quando você utilizou a abordagem do array, você manteve a declaração da propriedade dessa maneira: `public tabelaSerie = new clsTabela('Serie');` e é essa que não é modificada, é isso?

Comment: @KelvynRisso
public tblMaster - new clsTabelas('Master');

Comment: @MarceloVareladaSilva, e você adicionou no array `teste['Master'] = this.tblMaster` ou `teste['Master'] = new clsTabelas('Master')`?

Comment: @KelvynRisso
public tblMaster = new clsTabelas('Master');
public tblDetail =  new clsTabelas('Detail',{'MasterSource': this.tblMaster});

this.tblMaster.locate(4);
A tabela tblDetail automaticamente leria os dados da chave master '4'.

Mas para eu observar esta mudança dentro da nova classe criada tblDetail o parâmetro MasterSource querecebe o objeto classe tblMaster teria que ser twowaydatabinding e não estático como ele fica.

Comment: @MarceloVareladaSilva, acho que entendi, typescript/javascript, por padrão receberiam parâmetros do tipo objeto por referência, então você alterando em qualquer um dos lados, ambos deveriam ser alterados. Então nesse caso pode ser problema de escopo, e tua propriedade só é válida no escopo de criação. Talvez você possa mudar a tua instância para `public tblDetail = new clsTabelas('Detail', this.tblMaster);` para ver se tem impacto.

Comment: @KelvynRisso , sim, assim foi como falei com injeção de dependência que funciona. É que por uma organização atual e principalmente futura eu gostaria de passar o objeto no array de parâmetros ou passar o string com o nome apenas e lá dentro acessar o objeto.

Comment: @KelvynRisso Atualmente eu faço assim `public tblDetail = new clsTabelas('Detail', this.tblMaster, this._Http);`, tenho que injetar a tabela master e também o httpclient pois não consigo instanciar ele dentro da classe, quando era apenas http eu instanciava lá dentro em umas 6 linhas, mas agora não consigo mais.